# How to get the value from switch-toggle yes/no

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user selects yes/no in the switch the value is not printing.

Am using the switch toggle like in this link

When I submit it should show the value as whether yes or no.

`Demo below:` 
http://devgrow.com/iphone-style-switches/

Code below:

```
<p class="field switch">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="field"  checked />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="field" />
<label for="radio1" class="cb-enable selected"><span>Enable</span></label>
<label for="radio2" class="cb-disable"><span>Disable</span></label>
</p>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".cb-enable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

});
$(".cb-disable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

});
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: am using the same code in the given link..

Comment: Post the code here, external links go bad over time and most people don't like visiting external sites and sifting through their code. Post the relevant stuff here.

Comment: i edited the post with my code..

Comment: Where are you trying to get the value? Server-side or client-side?

Comment: "When user selects yes/no in the switch the value is not printing"  That's because you're not attempting to print it anywhere.

Comment: 2 scenarios for getting values one is am passing json object through handlebars js. Another one, user can select any option by clicking on enable/disable.

Comment: Patrick, here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gkMAv/

Comment: You seem to be missing the CSS.

Comment: CSS is not a problem, I can make use of radiobuttons itself..

Comment: Then why are you using this code? The whole point of the code on the page that you linked is to style the options a certain way. If you're simply wanting to know how to post form values to a server, that's what HTML/PHP tutorials are for.

Comment: Here is the link to original code http://devgrow.com/iphone-style-switches/. css is not applying correctly in jsfiddle..